# Few files on production are not working asp.net c# 3.5

Tags: c#, development-environment, asp.net-3.5, production-environment, dev-to-production

I created an ASP.NET C# site using .NET Framework 3.5. Its working fine on development server.
I have two folders namely

```
signup
settings
```

I than hosted my site to domain [somee](http://www.somee.com) everything is working fine on domain except the folder  `signup`. aspx page is loading but clicking on buttons leads me to custom error of setting custom error mode to `Off`. nothing is logged in logs and no stacktrace is there, please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: have you tried what the error message suggests : set the custom error mode to `Off`?

Comment: i set the error mode to off, but still same page appears. i also tried to move site on aspspider.com. both folders didn't worked there. somee is showing error on signup folder only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken ready folder which is created by default by MS Visual Studio?

In this case, please check the web.config, if exist check its details, and if not check the main folder, and there find and configure web.config, for the same.

I believe this should solve the error :)